# Can background window focus on mouseover be configured to update the Alt+Tab order?

Tags: windows-7, focus, alt-tab, window-focus

I'm using Windows 7's focus follows cursor model, without raise to front. Unfortunately, the Alt+Tab MRU order isn't updated to reflect the focus change. Here's the behavior (^ indicates focus in Alt+Tab order):

Order Before Mouse-Focus Change:

```
A > B > C
^
```

Order After Mouse-Focus on 'B' (the bad behavior):

```
A > B > C
    ^
```

Desired Order After Mouse-Focus on 'B' (normal Alt+Tab swapping behavior):

```
B > A > C
^
```

With many windows, this is a royal pain because Alt+Tab cycles to the right. I'd prefer to use Alt+Tab regularly, with the occasional cursor movement to get to a less-frequently-used window. Can the desired behavior be achieved in Windows 7?

"update order on focus" instead of "update order on raise" is what I'm after.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.yancylent.com/2010/03/11/windows-7-alt-tab-order/) what you mean?

Comment: The problem described there never occurred for me. If I switch windows using Alt+Tab, the previously-focused window and the newly focused window are swapped, placing the newly-focused window into position #1, appropriately preserving MRU alt+tab behavior. It's only when I use mouse-focus that the window positions are not swapped.